# Change Url with reactjs Infinite scrolling

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have implemented infinite-scroller without using any package. Now I want to add url parameters in url while scrolling page. there is an example of that.

https://www.livingshop.dk/gaveideer/

https://www.livingshop.dk/gaveideer/#/page/2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: it is divided into components, too messy. What i have done is just append data array on scroll event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

If you using react-router: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation